# HF RFID 13.56MHz Interference from WiFi/BLE 2.45GHz?

Tags: bluetooth, antenna, wifi, rfid, interference

If a Wifi/BLE antenna were placed within a multicoil loop antenna for 13.56MHz HF RFID, would there be significant crosstalk/interference?

Comment: What frequency is the WiFi and is the crosstalk problem for the WiFi or for the RFID system?

Comment: This is just for understanding.  If there were a 2.45GHz trace antenna placed within a 13.56MHz loop antenna, would it couple very significantly.... would either the 13.56 pick up the 2.45, or the 2.45 pickup the 13.56, or neither